How could we manage separate sessions in Spring Security via @PathVariable?
Imagine we have a customized way of authentication for the below URLs.
Path1: http://www.example.com/company1/home
Path2: http://www.example.com/company2/home
Path3: http://www.example.com/company3/home
.
.
.
PathX: http://www.example.com/companyX/home

And companies have different sets of data.
Now, I want spring security to create separate sessions for each of the above urls based on http://www.example.com/{company}/. So, when I login into different URLs in separate browser tabs, I can work with all of them. I want to keep all sessions alive and avoid session termination after the authentication with the other URLs.
How to achieve this?

Do you currently use a gateway?
https://spring.io/blog/2019/08/16/securing-services-with-spring-cloud-gateway

@gtatarsky no I'm not using any gateway

I would recommend it for your use case. Building a gateway is def the solution to your question and is a fairly simple impl. It will help with session seperation:
https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway

Thank you for this suggestion.. I'm checking if this solution can help out

@gtatarsky API gateway send request into different servers. In our case, we have 1 single Spring MVC project in the backend and we just want to create sessions based on relative URL http://www.example.com/*/home which * could be anything. How API Gateway could address this problem?

You can achieve this behavior by overriding the behavior of DefaultCookieSerializer#getCookiePath method, and set your own cookiePath strategy
Duplicate the DefaultCookieSerializer class and name it as MyCookieSerializer. (You can't override getCookiePath method in your child class because that method is private)
public class MyCookieSerializer implements CookieSerializer {
    //..codes above
    private String getCookiePath(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (this.cookiePath == null) {
            //SecurityUtils#getSiteName: this method just extract the company name from the path. You may have your own strategy
            String siteName = SecurityUtils.getSiteName(request.getServletPath());
            return siteName != null ? "/" + siteName + "/" : "/";
        }
        return this.cookiePath;
    }
    //..codes below
}

Create a bean of your MyCookieSerializer
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.something"
})
@PropertySource( { "classpath:application.properties" } )
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Value("${cookie.max.age}")
    private int cookieMaxAge;


    @Bean
    public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
        MyCookieSerializer marlin = new MyCookieSerializer();
        marlin.setCookieMaxAge(cookieMaxAge);
        return marlin;
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvc) throws Exception {
        return http
            .sessionManagement(httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer -> {
                httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.sessionFixation().none();
                httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED);
                httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.maximumSessions(-1);

            })
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(
                                antMatcher("/"),
                                antMatcher("/css/**"),
                                antMatcher("/fonts/**"),
                                antMatcher("/js/**"),
                                antMatcher("/images/**"),
                                antMatcher("/*/")
                        ).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/{id}/**")).authenticated())
                         //Your Authentication method codes (e.g formLogin, basic, etc)
                        .build();

That's it.
I explain here how this works:

when the first user request http://www.example.com/company1/home on the first tab, a cookie with path /company1/ will be created and put in response by MyCookieSerializer. This is used by browser in subsequent requests coming from company1.
When we open another tab and put http://www.example.com/company2/home, since the previous cookie path is set to /company1/, the session associated with that cookie won't send to the server during the request process of company2. Hence, when the server receive the request without session, it creates another session for company2 and put that in a cookie (again by CookieSerializer) during the response. and Company2 can also use that cookie for its subsequent requests.

This works in all scenarios. For example if we logout company1 which is on tab1, company2 will still works and its session will remain active.
I hope I explain the process properly for you.

SessionRepository is responsible for creating, retrieving, and persisting sessions. Hence, you must implement a custom SessionRepositry and Session strategy.
Custom SessionRepository would be responsible for storing sessions based on the URL path. Then we have to configure spring security to use the custom SessionRepository.
The implementation would be mostly in the following lines:
@Component    
public class CustomSessionRepository implements SessionRepository<Session> {
        private final Map<String, Map<String, Session>> session = new HashMap<>(); //map to store the URL path to a map of session id and session object
    
        @override
        public Session createSession() {
            return new MapSession(); // or any other Session Implementation 
        }
    
        @Override
        public void save(Session session) {
            String path = getPathFromSession(session);
            sessions.computeIfAbsent(path, k -> new HashMap<>()).put(session.getId, session);
        }
    
        @Override
        public Session findById(String id) {
           String path = getPathFromRequest();
           return sessions.getOrDefault(path, new HashMap<>()).get(id)
        }
    
        @Override
        public void deleteById(String id) {
            String path = getPathFromRequest();
            sessions.getOrDefault(path, new HashMap<>()).remove(id);       
        }
    
        private String getPathFromSession(Session session) {
           return session.getAttribute("path");
        }
    
        private String getPathFromRequest() {
           HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
          return request.getRequestURI().split("/")[2]; //uri path format /companyX/
        }
    }

In the Security config, you must register the customSessionRepository for the paths. Normally, you should have a separate method to fetch the path dynamically to make the program configurable:
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig {
    
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity HTTP) throws Exception {
    
          http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/company1/**", "/company2/**", "/company3/**")
         .authenticate().and()
         .formLogin().and()
         .sessionManagement()
         .sessionFixation().none()
         .sessionRepository(customSessionRepository());
          return http.build();
    }
    
        @Bean
        public CustomSessionRepository customSessionRepository() {
            return new CustomSessionRegistry();
        }
    
    }


We are using Redis so we have RedisSessionRepository and Redis to store our sessions. But I tweak that and try your solution. If it worked I will mark it as the answer.

please refer to my answer, I explained it there

You need to use Spring Session in your Spring Security configuration.
I see that you are using Redis already in your Spring Boot Application to store sessions. So, that's great. I guess you already had this dependencies in your pom.xml given below:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

If not please add them.
These spring boot dependencies will make sure that all of stuffs related to session stored on redis is managed by default autoconfiguration classes provided by the above starter packages. But in case, if you want to add custom configuration logic of handling session with Redis using Spring Boot, then refer to doc attached here.

You need to use MvcRequestMatcher.Builder from Spring Security to match URLs containing the @PathVariable.
Example:
Let's say you have a controller given below and I assumed that UI frameworks like thymeleaf is already setup in the project :
@RestController
public class CompanyController {

    @GetMapping("/{company}/home")
    public ModelAndView companyHomePage(@PathVariable("company") String company) {
        // name of the page (home -> home.html)
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("home");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{company}/dashboard")
    public ModelAndView companyDashboard(@PathVariable("company") String company) {
        // name of the page (dashboard -> dashboard.html)
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("dashboard");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}

Configure your spring security by taking the below code as reference:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.servlet.util.matcher.MvcRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
public class CustomSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
        MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcher = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> registry.requestMatchers(mvcMatcher.pattern("/{company}/**")).authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(sessionConfigurer -> sessionConfigurer.sessionFixation()
                        .none().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED));
        return http.build();
    }

}

Few points to be noted:

By default, old HTTP Session are invalidated when new ones are created. This can be controlled via sessionFixation. This code -> sessionFixation().none() will make sure the old session are not invalidated.

You can set a custom session creation policy and set that policy in the HttpSecurity configuration as well. This code -> .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED) will make sure that session is created only if it's needed. It's a default behaviour and just added for reference.

mvcMatcher.pattern("/{company}/**") will make sure that match URLs http://www.example.com/company1/home, http://www.example.com/company2/home


See if this helps.

I knew all of the above. But my question is about how to create that custom session on multi user, multi-tab environment

@Mehdi I read here that spring session keeps track of multiple sessions per user, by using a session alias parameter called _s.

dude that is per user, we want per multi user per multi tab

@Mehdi Okay got it.

I explained the process I went into to achieve this. Please refer to my answer
